# Getting row count with Result Set

Tags: java

Please Help !!!!!!!
In DB I have 2 rows with this query.

---

```
SELECT D.DEALER_CODE 
FROM SCOTT.T_DEALERSHIP D,SCOTT.T_DEALER_BILLING DB 
WHERE D.DEALER_CODE = DB.DEALER_CODE 
    AND DEALER_NAME LIKE 'XTIME%'
    AND (RNR_CUST_NUM = '546' OR RNR_CUST_NUM = '43356'OR RNR_CUST_NUM = '7637055' OR RNR_CUST_NUM ='7637055' OR RNR_CUST_NUM IS NULL) 
    AND (RCI_STORE_NUMBER IS NULL OR  RCI_STORE_NUMBER = '05')
    AND (RCI_AREA_NUMBER = '01'OR  RCI_AREA_NUMBER IS NULL) 
    AND (RCI_DEALER_NUMBER IS NULL AND DEALER_Address1 LIKE UPPER('1500 ORACLE%')                                
    AND DEALER_CITY =UPPER('BAKERSFIELD') AND DEALER_ZIP LIKE'6%')
```

With below code, I get only 1 row when there are 2 records in DB. When there is only one record in DB it works but not when there are more records. Also `rs.last()` method gets skipped and exits resultset. I have to comment it to execute for one record. I do not want to use `COUNT`.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
System.out.println("" + sql1);

while(rs.next()) {
    rs.last();
    int Rows = rs.getRow();
    System.out.println("Rows are " + Rows);
}
```

Comment: `last()` states : `Moves the cursor to the last row in this ResultSet object.` Do you want that?

Comment: No. If it does not give me expected result I don't want to. All I want is count records from DB. If it is 0 /1/ more than 1. If I comment it program executes but does not give me correct count when there is more than one record.

Comment: Why not do a count?  That is precisely what you need.  So if your query matches a million rows, you want to return all million to your app just to count how many there are?

Comment: Initially I used count. But I also need to get this value from DB - Dealer_Code.(rs.getString("DEALER_CODE"). If I use count I may not be able to get this column. Please Help.                                                                                             select COUNT(*)

Comment: I cannot recall this but... if the index starts at 0, then 1 is the right answer. {0, 1} That might be why you got 1 while printing 1. But I can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is count the records in the database, then you should really use a query of the form `SELECT count(*) FROM ...`. If you really need to perform the query the way you listed above, then you want to set a counter variable outside your `while` loop like so:

```
int rowNum = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    rowNum++;
}
System.out.println("Number of records: "+rowNum);
```

Comment: I tried this one too.. no luck:(  int rowcount = 0;
                                                 
                             while(rs.next()){
                                                                    String DealerCode =  rs.getString("DEALER_CODE");
                       System.out.println("Dealer Code" + DealerCode);
                                 
                       int Rows = rowcount++;
                             if (Rows == 1){
                            stmt.getConnection();
                          ***upda

Comment: If you want to execute code on each iteration, you might want to update your question to reflect that. On a quick inspection, though, if you're looking for the `if (Rows==1)` bit to execute on the first row you get back, you want to either a) set `Rows` using `++rowcount` instead of `rowcount++` or b) just use the count variable directly instead of resetting it in each iteration: `rowcount++; if (rowcount==1) {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend against returning all the data to Java via JDBC just to determine the number of rows.  If you just want to know how many rows match the condition, then do a select count(*) query:

In SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SCOTT.T_DEALERSHIP D,SCOTT.T_DEALER_BILLING DB
WHERE D.DEALER_CODE = DB.DEALER_CODE
    AND DEALER_NAME LIKE 'XTIME%'
    AND (RNR_CUST_NUM = '546' OR RNR_CUST_NUM = '43356'OR RNR_CUST_NUM = '7637055' OR RNR_CUST_NUM ='7637055' OR RNR_CUST_NUM IS NULL) 
    AND (RCI_STORE_NUMBER IS NULL OR  RCI_STORE_NUMBER = '05')
    AND (RCI_AREA_NUMBER = '01'OR  RCI_AREA_NUMBER IS NULL)
    AND (RCI_DEALER_NUMBER IS NULL AND DEALER_Address1 LIKE UPPER('1500 ORACLE%')
    AND DEALER_CITY =UPPER('BAKERSFIELD') AND DEALER_ZIP LIKE'6%')
```

Then in Java:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
System.out.println("" + sql1);

int rows = 0;
if(rs.next()) {
    rows = rs.getInt();
}
System.out.println("Rows are " + rows);
```

**Edit based on OP's comments**

To get the values from the database in addition to the count, just scan the values.

SQL:

```
SELECT D.DEALER_CODE
FROM SCOTT.T_DEALERSHIP D,SCOTT.T_DEALER_BILLING DB
WHERE D.DEALER_CODE = DB.DEALER_CODE
    AND DEALER_NAME LIKE 'XTIME%'
    AND (RNR_CUST_NUM = '546' OR RNR_CUST_NUM = '43356'OR RNR_CUST_NUM = '7637055' OR RNR_CUST_NUM ='7637055' OR RNR_CUST_NUM IS NULL)
    AND (RCI_STORE_NUMBER IS NULL OR  RCI_STORE_NUMBER = '05')
    AND (RCI_AREA_NUMBER = '01'OR  RCI_AREA_NUMBER IS NULL)
    AND (RCI_DEALER_NUMBER IS NULL AND DEALER_Address1 LIKE UPPER('1500 ORACLE%')
    AND DEALER_CITY =UPPER('BAKERSFIELD') AND DEALER_ZIP LIKE'6%')
```

Java:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);
System.out.println("" + sql1);

List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) {
    rows.add(rs.getString());
}
System.out.println("There are " + rows.size() + " rows.");
```

Comment: Initially I used count. But I also need to get this value from DB - Dealer_Code.(rs.getString("DEALER_CODE"). If I use count I may not be able to get this column. Please Help

Comment: Well, that wasn't the code you posted.  If you need the values and you need the count, just start a counter at 0 and increment as you iterate.  Or, check the collection size at the end.

Comment: Updated with a solution to both of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks All. This worked while(rs.next()){                                                           
                       DealerCode =  rs.getString("DEALER_CODE");
                       System.out.println("Dealer Code " + DealerCode);
                  
                       Rows = ++rowcount;
                           }